# How i need to look up with in the table for exact match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SYS.OBJECTS kind of a table in my Database (i.e. Dbo.tables) where I have data like this

**Sample Data**

```
Tbl_name    Col_names   Query
H_Website   Website_ID  SELECT W.WebSiteID, C.Channel_ID FROM   Enroll W LEFT JOIN CHANNEL_TYPE C ON W.ChannelNAME = C.ChannelNAME
```

If I execute the query which is there in query column I will get website ID from Enroll table . So actually enroll table have Website ID column. 
How can I do the lookup for Website ID in Query column and get the table name (Enroll table which have Website ID column name)

**The output I need to get that**

```
Tbl_name   Col_names   Source_Tbl
H_Website  Website_ID   Enroll
```

The out put I need to get that and I'm unable to move forward on this. Enlighten me on this.

Thanks

Comment: A general solution here might be hard to swing, because SQL Server does not have any regex like capabilities.

Comment: Are you asking how to find _substring_ in a text? By the way, the query is broken: columns a prefixed with orphaned aliases.

Comment: @IvanStarostin sorry for orphaned aliases I will modify the question

Answer (score 0):

```
use test_db

SELECT      t.name AS 'TableName'
            ,c.name  AS 'ColumnName'

FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id

where   t.name like '%tbl_name%'

ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a lot more useful if you provided an explanation as to *how* it answers it.

Comment: sys.tables is table name in your database and sys.columns is columns name in table. When you create a table, table name is added to sys.tables. same way columns name is added to sys.columns

Answer (score 0):

This might be a pain in the neck, since SQL does not have the full support of regex (expressions). So, searching inside a string with that complexity will be very tough to handle. The reason that I see it complex it's because you've only provide a simple query. While there are windowed queries, CTE, loops ...etc. So, you'll need to come up with a different and easiest way to do it. Otherwise, it'll be a long ride !

here is an example that will be applied on your example (works on simple queries that only has one `FROM`) :

```
DECLARE     
    @t  TABLE(Tbl_name VARCHAR(250), Col_names VARCHAR(250), Query VARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('H_Website','Website_ID','SELECT W.WebSiteID, C.Channel_ID FROM Enroll W LEFT JOIN CHANNEL_TYPE C ON W.ChannelNAME = C.ChannelNAME')



SELECT  
    Tbl_name
,   Col_names
,   RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(SecondPart, CHARINDEX(' ', SecondPart)))) Source_Tbl
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LTRIM(SUBSTRING(FirstPart, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstPart) , LEN(FirstPart) )) SecondPart
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Tbl_name
        ,   Col_names
        ,   LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Query,CHARINDEX(' FROM ',Query), 50 )) FirstPart
        FROM @t
    ) D
) C
```